# Traducciones que faltan en la ficha de usuario

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones

**Editar Perfil**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Full name

Nombre Completo

> Birthday (only used for displaying age)

Fecha de nacimiento (usada solamente para mostrar la edad)

---

**Preferencias**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Q&A Emails

> Sign up for a weekly email with top questions and answers, important announcements and unanswered questions (see an example newsletter).

---

**Ocultar Comunidades**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. It does not, however, mean your activity is private.

Comment: ¡Hola @joc! Me he permitido quitar la mención a la lista de privilegios y la lista en sí de tu pregunta, porque 1) es mejor ceñir la pregunta a sólo una parte del sitio (como ya haces en el título) y 2) ya hay otra pregunta que hace referencia a las traducciones de la lista de privilegios: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/750/falta-traducir-texto-en-los-privilegios-del-sitio. Disculpa las molestias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de traducir esos textos y he pulsado el "botón rojo", de forma que los textos correctos serán visibles tras la próxima compilación. Gracias.